# Hide UISearchBar with UITableViewController, UISearchDisplayController and 'automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'd like to have the `UISearchBar` be initially hidden behind the navigation bar using the `UITableView`'s `contentInset` and `contentOffset`, however, I can't seem to get `UITableViewController`, `UISearchDisplayController` and `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to play nice.

If I set the `contentInset`, the controller will reset it when displayed.

Setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `NO` hides the table under the `UINavigationBar` and won't respond to me setting the `UIViewController`'s `view` property (in order to change the frame). If I override `loadView` and set the view directly, it removes the `UITableView` and just setting the `frame` doesn't have any effect.

Is this possible in iOS 7?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you were looking to do (and I know ages have passed) but this will start your search bar hidden if the search bar is embedded in the TableView header.

```
- (void) hideSearchBar
{
    CGPoint contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset;
    contentOffset.y += CGRectGetHeight(self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame);       //  hide the Search Bar until dragged down
    self.tableView.contentOffset = contentOffset;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant answer this is. Takes into account the tableviews own initial content offset.